# C++ DLL Issue missing Certificate

Tags: c++, dllimport

I am new to C++ and trying to convert existing C++ code to DLL so that i can call from C-sharp by DLL import. The code C++ does encryption and decryption.

I have successfully executed the functionality in C++ console application as exe. However, when i converted same code to DLL and tried to run from different C++ console application by importing DLL then I am unable to load the application because within the same DLL code I have one certificate which is part of the resource folder and it should be available within the execution.

I am not sure why DLL is unable to find the certificate though I manually placed the certificate.

Any ideas ?

Regards,
Zeeshan Qureshi

Comment: My crystal ball tells me because your DLL is using `FindResource(NULL,...)` to locate your resource-table-stored certificate, and is not finding it because `NULL` uses the *process* instance, not the DLL module instance for resource resolution. Without related code, all you're going to get out of this is sheer speculation and wags (wild-ass-guesses). That was mine.

Comment: You are right!  Here is the code CBuffer CSystem::LoadBuffer(LPCTSTR szName, LPCTSTR szType, HINSTANCE hInstance/*=NULL*/)
{
HRSRC   hResource;
HGLOBAL hGlobal;
LPVOID  pBuffer;
int     nSize;

if ((hResource = ::FindResource(hInstance, szName, szType)) == NULL) return CBuffer();
if ((nSize    = ::SizeofResource(hInstance, hResource)) == 0)   return CBuffer();
if ((hGlobal   = ::LoadResource(hInstance,  hResource)) == NULL)  return CBuffer();
if ((pBuffer   = ::LockResource(hGlobal)) == NULL)      return CBuffer();
return CBuffer((BYTE*)pBuffer, nSize);
}//-----------

Comment: I assume then you addressed this by saving of your DLL instance handle from DLLMain's `PROCESS_ATTACH` in some global `hInstDLL`, then using `FindResource(hInstDLL, ...)`, or something similar. That should solve your issue if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Sorry for ignorance. Not really sure, what do you mean by Process_Attach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By invoking `FindResource(NULL, ...)` you're using the *process* resource table for resolution, not the DLL's. This would work when this was all in one EXE, but by moving your code to a DLL, and the resources with it, you need to look in the DLL module's resource table instead.

Your `DllMain` for your DLL, should look something like this, and add one if you don't have one yet:

```
HINSTANCE hInstDLL; // <=== LOOK HERE (added global)

BOOLEAN WINAPI DllMain( 
         IN HINSTANCE hDllHandle, 
         IN DWORD     nReason, 
         IN LPVOID    Reserved )
 {
    switch ( nReason )
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            hInstDLL = hDllHandle; // <<=== LOOK HERE (set global)
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

From that your `FindResource` invoke should use `hInstDLL` as the first argument, not `NULL`. That should get your resource lookup to use the proper resource table.

Best of luck.

Comment: Where I will add this code ? again apologize for asking a very basic question ? I should add it in Stdafx. cpp ?

Comment: add it to any *single* source file you want. Look on MSDN for [more info on DllMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: then move it to the one already defined. Its somewhere in your code source base. That would be the part where I mentioned "...  and add one **if you don't have one yet**". One way or another, you need the DLL's module instance handle if you wish to load resources from its resource table. To get that instance handle, you have to retrieve it from `DllMain()`s parameters at load-time. That is the point of this answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got your point clearly, and modified a cpp file wherein I have exposed functions for C#, after deploying I am still getting the same error. What else I can do!?

Comment: You could always debug it and make sure the `hInstDLL` is properly being set and used properly (which I still suspect it is not). You did add the cert to the .rc via a custom resource type, right? You must have or it wouldn't have worked in the EXE project, but in moving everything to a DLL, you may want to make sure the resources are properly setup as well. I'll tell you now, this *cannot* turn into an online-debugging seminar. Debug your program and make sure (a) the resource is in the DLL's resource table, and (b) the `hInstDLL` is properly set in `DllMain()`.

Comment: BOOL WINAPI
DllMain (HANDLE hDll, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (dwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
          std::cout << "\n DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH";
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
             std::cout << "\n DLL_PROCESS_DETACH";
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
           std::cout << "\n DLL_THREAD_ATTACH";
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
             std::cout << "\n DLL_THREAD_DETACH";
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}I am able to call this function but now where to put DLL handler

Comment: **You Don't Call It**. Windows calls it when it loads your DLL. In the process it *hands* you the instance handle you seek. I quite-literally cannot possibly fathom a more concise and clear explanation than that. And dumping data to `std::out` in DllMain is a **bad** idea. I *strongly* suggest you read the link I provided over an hour ago on `DllMain()` ([**click here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Comment: Got it and it worked, but another problem occured. C++ code is trying to read the cert from mystore but its failing. HCERTSTORE from CertFindCertificateInStore. code is in DLL and i am calling from another console application